# Solving differential equation $y'(x)=e^{a(x+y)}+3e^{ay}$ if $a \neq 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation is given below marked with (*).
[image]

I have to determine the complete solution to (*) if $\alpha \neq 0$. I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I am thinking that it has something to do with Bernoulli's differential equation but I tend to make mistakes when calculating. Sorry if this is too much to ask for but I need help with elementary steps for this problem.

The theory:
The Bernoulli's differential equation has the form:

$\dot x= Q(t)x + R(t)x^n$ (1)

where $Q(t)$ and $R(t)$ are continuous functions and $x=x(t)$. The equation is linear if $n = 0$ and separable if $n = 1$. If $n \neq 1$ and $x(t) \gt 0 $ for all $t$. Then dividing equation (1) by $x^n$ we get:

$x^{-n}\dot x = Q(t)x^{1-n}+R(t) $

A new unknown function $z=z(t)$ is defined by:

$z = x^{1-n}$ (2)

So $\dot z =(1-n)x^{-n}\dot x$ inserting in (1) gives:

$\frac{1}{1-n}\dot z = Q(t)z + R(t)$

as a linear differential equation to determination of $z=z(t)$. When $z(t)$ is found, then we use (2) to find

$x(t)=z(t)^{1/(1-n)}$

which is the solution to (1).

In my case I don't know what $n$ is. Or is it $\alpha$? What is $Q(t)$ and $R(t)$ in my case? How do I approach this problem?

Attempt:

$\int \frac{1}{e^{\alpha y}} dy = \int e^{\alpha x} + 3 dx $

$-\frac{1}{\alpha}e^{-\alpha y} = \frac{1}{\alpha}e^{\alpha x}+3x+C$, $C \in \Bbb R $

$ e^{-\alpha y} = -e^{\alpha x} - 3\alpha x - C\alpha $

$ -y\alpha  = ln (-e^{\alpha x} -3\alpha x - C\alpha) $

$ y = -\frac{1}{\alpha}ln (-e^{\alpha x} -3\alpha x - C\alpha)$

Can anyone tell me if this is correct?

My teacher get the results to be:

$ y = -\frac{1}{\alpha}ln (-e^{\alpha x} -3\alpha x + C) $

which I don't get why it's $ + C$ and not $-C\alpha$ in the equation.

Comment: Why are you expanding on Bernoulli's equations to solve a differential equation not in this class?

Answer (score 3):

The equation is separable since it can be written

$$ e^{-\alpha y} \frac {dy}{dx} = e^{\alpha x} + 3 $$

Comment: Thank you! I was also thinking that the equation was separable but for some odd reason I couldn't separate it.. I tend to make basic mistakes.. >.<

Comment: Wait a minute. I did do this but still couldn't get to the right answer..  brb..